# Is there an equivalent to shap (Python) in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, shap

I'm currently working in spark scala. I need to calculate some shapley values. And I can't find any package equivalent to the python shap 's one.
Is there any equivalent in scala ?
If not, I'm currently working on a project where I need to explain the biggest mistakes the ml algo does. If any of you have some tips or advice, it would be welcomed!

PS : English is not my mother tongue, I might have done big mistakes.

Comment: Not yet to my knowledge. PySpark only,